# Sonarqube not analyzing super class equals and potentially throwing a false positive for NPE

Tags: java, sonarqube

Here is an example:

```
public class A{
    public boolean equals(Object a){
        if(a == null)
            return false;
         // Some Implementation
    }

}

public class B extends A {
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(this == obj)
            return true;
        if(!super.equals(obj)) // null check for obj is already there in super.equals
            return false;
        if(getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        // Some Implementation
    }

}
```

The rule for the issue observed is *A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "obj" is nullable here.* My question is, what's the best way to handle such scenarios? Wouldn't the analysis not be able to always to identify the null check in `super.equals(obj)` ?

Comment: Is class A in a different file?

Comment: Yes! Is there a workaround to resolve this by keeping them in different files? Still not sure how the current code would be logically incorrect.

Comment: Which detector is reporting the issue?

Comment: squid:S2259  - https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/tag/cert/RSPEC-2259 . Not sure if this is what you were looking for @ThomasJensen ?

Comment: Yes, that info was missing from the question. So it's not a [findbugs] question, as indicated by your tag. Go with @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam's advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comments indicate that the two classes are in separate files. That's why the issue is not suppressed; cross-file analysis just isn't available in SonarJava.

Your best course is to mark this a False Positive and move on.